# "Trade-off" between bound on the function and on the spectrum for functional calculus in spectral theory

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, unbounded-operators, functional-calculus

Let $A$ be a self-adjoint (unbounded) operator on a separable Hilbert space $H$.
From the following form of spectral theorem, we may define a functional calculus by $f(A)=Q^{-1} M_{f\circ \alpha} Q$. (See below for $Q,\alpha$.)

> There exists an at most countable collection of finite Borel measures $(\mu_k)$ on $\mathbb R$ and a isometric linear map $Q:L^2(X,\mu) \to H$, where $(X,\mu)=\bigsqcup_{k}(\mathbb R , \mu_k)$ is the disjoint union of copies of $\mathbb R$, such that
> $$
> Q^{-1}AQ=M_\alpha, \text{Domain}(A)=D(A)=QD(M_\alpha),
> $$
> where $\alpha:X \to \mathbb R$ is given by $\alpha(x)=x$ on each copy of $\mathbb R$ and $M_\alpha$ is the multiplication operator corresponding to $\alpha$ on $L^2(X,\mu)$.

This is a version of spectral theorem found in *Spectral Theory -
Basic Concepts and Applications* by David Borthwick. It is also proven in the book that this functional calculus is well-defined for all **bounded** borel functions $\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ (Theorem 5.9). However, this does not include many functions. For example, polynomial functions, like $f(x)=x$, are unbounded.

On the other hand, it is very easy to see that functional calculus for polynomials can easily be defined in this way, **if** $A$ is a **bounded operator**, because it has a **bounded** spectrum.

**It appears that, to make the functional calculus work, we have to place a limit on either the "size" of spectrum of $A$ or the "growth rate" of $f$?**

Can the above statement be made more precise? Are there any nice descriptions of this "trade-off"?

**EDIT:** Proof in the book that the functional calculus is unique (and hence well-defined) is based on the fact that $\|f(A)\|\leq \sup_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} |f(\lambda)|$, which often does not make sense for unbounded functions $f$. What are some alternative ways to overcome this to establish that it is well-defined (i.e. independent of the choice of $Q$) for unbounded functions as well?

Comment: The operator $f(A)$ is of course well-defined for any (finite) Borel function $f$. However, "functional calculus" likely refers to properties like $f(A)g(A) = (fg)(A)$ and $f(g(A)) = (f\circ g)(A)$, which requires some extra assumptions (such as boundedness) on $f$ and $g$ in order to domains of both sides of these equations be equal. Off the top of my head, I do not know of any other reasonable condition for that, other than, say, $f$ and $g$ are non-zero polynomials.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki How to prove that it is well-defined for any (a.e. finite) Borel function? (See my edit above.)

Comment: I'd say the following two papers by Markus Haase are for you: [reference 1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.04733) and [reference 2](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.06130)